# Relaunch batch apex failed start

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a batch, and I don´t know the reason because this batch sometimes fail. Its random, I execute other time and its correct
The fail is in START:

> First error: [REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for
>   too long, and has been stopped.

I cant do more optimus the query of batch, so I need a process that if this batch fail, automatically its relaunch

Comment: What number of records are you trying to query in batch?

Comment: In the query 8k as much; so in the bbdd there is 25M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't recover from a governor limit, which this error is. The best you can do is turn on [Apex Error Reporting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170712&type=1), and have someone manually restart the process. Your best option is to optimize the query so that it does not fail. Remove any extra fields, adjust the filters, and remove any sub-queries from the query, if possible, and move them to the execute method. Despite what you may say, there is always a way to optimize a query or the batch process (consider asking a question where you provide your code and query to us so we can assist you).

Comment: The query is about an object that has 25million records in the bbdd, with a lot of joins and fields, and this query have a subquery.....
Is more optimun the query with some fields in execute that in START ?
When I run again, this process no fail, its randon :(

Comment: @Juanma Yes, run the main query in the `start` method, and run any child queries in `execute`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the "run it again if it fails" approach is going to help you. If it's long-running to begin with, it will likely be long running every other time you run it.

Can you not reduce the size of your batch scope by specifying a smaller number of records in your `Database.executeBatch(...)` method call?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

When we've come across issues like this in the past, we've had to reduce the size of our batches.